# Python pypeeter not working for page.evaluateOnNewDocument

Tags: javascript, python, dom, puppeteer, python-asyncio

I am using pypeeter for a web scraping project,

I have several page.evaluage functions and works fine,

but whenever I run `await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(js_statement)`

```
js_statement ="""
                        () =>{
                            Object.defineProperties(navigator,{ webdriver:{ get: () => false } });
                            window.navigator.chrome = { runtime: {},  };
                            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', { get: () => ['en-US', 'en'] });
                            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', { get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6], });
                         }
                    """
```

I get only None, kindly help.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Can you show a [mcve] along with your expected result? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen, if you paste the above statement without ` () => ` in chrome console tab, its returning a json object, I'm expecting the same, Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect `evaluateOnNewDocument` to return a JSON object? (BTW, JSON is not an object, it's a string... do you mean a dict?). If you [check the docs](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html), the return value of `evaluateOnNewDocument` is `None` -- all it does is register a callback to run later when the page navigates. Did you mean `evaluate`, which runs immediately and returns serializable data from the browser console? What are you trying to achieve here on a high-level, exactly?